# How can i not expose my backend microservice using api gateway?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, api-gateway

I have an app that is deployed in k8s cluster and the frontend and the backend of the app are exposed, is there a way to not expose the backend ? i thought about the api gateway is it going to fulfills my requests if yes how ? and if not what's the alternatives ??

Thank you in advance

I tried the gateway kong and it did not work out very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question requires more detail for me to be certain, however I will take a stab at pointing you in the right direction.

Typically, most apps have a frontend which serves the HTML, and any static assets such as images, css and javascript (like a single page app such as ReactJS)
If you have some SPA, then you will likely have a backend API written in something like Node / Python / PHP / Java to serve your frontend app with dynamic data.

If your frontend and backend are exposed to the internet, this is OK and expected.

If your backend was not exposed to the internet, then it would be impossible for your frontend to load dynamic data.

That said, you mentioned that you are using or at least tried to use an API Gateway. Typically, you would not expose your backend *directly* to the internet. Rather, you would expose your API Gateway to the internet, with the API Gateway acting as a reverse proxy to your backend.

In order to achieve this (in Kubernetes), you would typically create a [Service type Load Balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) for your API Gateway. And configure a Service type Cluster IP for your backend.

> ClusterIP: Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default that is used if you don't explicitly specify a type for a Service. You can expose the service to the public with an Ingress or the Gateway API.

Comment: Thank you for your time the problem is solved using wso2 api gateway